# separate a column by groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is how my data looks:

[image]

This is the code I have come up with:

```
surgery_types = ["Ascendensvervanging", "AVR", "AVR + MVP", "Bentall", "CABG", "CABG + AVR", "CABG + MVP", "Epicardiale LV-lead", "Lobectomie of segmentresectie", "Mediastinoscopie", "MVP", "MVP + TVP", "Nuss","Refixatie sternum", "Staaldraden verwijderen", "VATS Boxlaesie", "Wondtoilet"]
```

This is the list of surgeries I need and rest I wanted to rename it to 'other_types'. I have 158 different types of surgeries. Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: your image is not showing

Comment: Now, it should show

Comment: Is this a pandas Dataframe?

Comment: Yes. It is a pandas dataframe

Comment: does the names that are in the `surgery_types` list are the exact same in surgery type column?

Comment: Yes exactly. You are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

boolean masking,`loc` accessor and `str.contains()`:

```
m=df['Surgery Type'].str.contains('|'.join(surgery_types),case=False)
#created a boolean mask
df.loc[~m,'Surgery Type']='other_types'
#pass that boolean mask(opposite) and changed value
```

OR

boolean masking,`loc` accessor and `isin()`:

```
m=df['Surgery Type'].isin(surgery_types)
#created a boolean mask
df.loc[~m,'Surgery Type']='other_types'
#pass that boolean mask(opposite) and changed value
```